# Does the function $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x}}$ have an oblique asymptote?

Tags: calculus

Does the function $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x}}$$ have an oblique asymptote? If so, how do we find it? I thought about long dividing, but that wouldn't work, because You can't divide square roots.

Comment: why not? $\frac{\sqrt{4}}{\sqrt{5}}$ exists..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not going to have an "oblique" asymptote like you are used to--it's *not* going to be a straight line.  Instead the "oblique asymptote" is going to be a sideways parabola.  This is because you have (essentially) $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}} = \sqrt{x}$--so the asymtptote is going to be a square root--or quadratic:

$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x + 1}} = x\frac{\sqrt{x + 1}}{x + 1}
$$

Put another way what you have is: $\sqrt{x + 1} = y \rightarrow y^2 = x+1 \rightarrow x = y^2 - 1$:

$$
\left(y^2 - 1\left)\frac{y}{y^2}\right.\right. = \frac{y^2 - 1}{y} = y - \frac{1}{y} = \sqrt{x + 1} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x + 1}}
$$

This means that the "oblique" asymptote is $y = \sqrt{x + 1}$.

Comment: $y = \sqrt{x + 1}$ is a curvilinear asymptote.  It is not oblique since an oblique asymptote is a line.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Hence why I put quotes around the term oblique...this function asymptotes to the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ as I stated--it doesn't _exactly_ asymptote to that, but it essentially does.

Comment: I knew you understood the question.  I just wanted to make sure that the person who posted the question understood why you put the quotes there.

Answer (score 3):

A necessary condition for the function $f$ to have an oblique asymptote at $\infty$ is that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}
$$
exists, is finite and is *non zero*. If the oblique asymptote exists, then this limit is its slope. It mustn't be zero, because otherwise it wouldn't be oblique in the first place.

---

If an oblique asymptote exists, with equation $y=mx+q$ ($m\ne0$), then, by definition,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-mx-q)=0
$$
so also
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)-mx-q}{x}=0
$$
and then
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}-m\right)=0
$$
because, of course, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{q}{x}=0$.

Comment: I don't see how an "oblique" asymptote differs from a $y = 0$ asymptote which you seem to single out.

Comment: @Jared A necessary condition for a horizontal asymptote is that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists finite, which should be checked before trying for oblique asymptotes.

Comment: @Jared The usual example is $f(x)=\log x$, which hasn't a horizontal asymptote, but $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x}}=\frac{x+1-1}{\sqrt{x+1}}=\sqrt{1+x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$$

Comment: This is a good answer (don't get me wrong)...but I hope you (the OP) will take the time to understand my answer as well.

Comment: @Jared My answer is purely a hint,yours is a complete answer :)

Comment: I agree, hence why I upvoted your answer as it agreed with mine...I would suggest the OP and others to do the same since it verifies the result (regardless of who came first).